# URL Rewrite on PHP with query string to SEO-friendly

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I am new to the URL rewrite rules and would like to rewrite some URLs. Below is my problem:

I have created two rules (which works fine) that will hide the *.php extension from the URL. One is to redirect "/abc.php" to "/abc". Another rule is to Rewrite /abc as /abc.php. These two rules work fine and I use the following pattern.

- `^([^/]+)/?\.php$`  --> Redirects to --> `{R:1}`
- `^([^/]+)/?$` --> Rewrites to --> `{R:1}.php`

Now I have a problem. I have a page which goes like `www.example.com/member?getuser=chris`   (note that it's not `member.php?getuser=chrisyeung` because of the previous rules). I want to rewrite the URL to:

```
www.example.com/member/chris
```

I tried to follow some tutorials and use the following pattern:

```
`^/member/(_[0-0a-z-]+)` --> Rewrites to --> `^member?getuser={R:1}`.
```

...but it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

[image: screenshot of edit outbound rule]
[image: screenshot 2 of edit outbound rule]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't unterstand your first two rules. Rewrite `*.php` to `*` and `*` to `*.php` - sounds like a loop for me. I assume your files are named `.php` and you want your visitors use URLs w/o this file extension. Then just rewrite `*` to `*.php`.

For your members pages, use:

```
^/member/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+) member.php?getuser={R:1} [QSA]
```

I changes the list of valid characters inside the `[]` and I call `member.php` directly - no need for issuing another rule. `QSA` is for passing through further URL params.

Comment: Thank you for the answer posted. To reply to the first part of your answer, I used two rules because one is used to rewrite and the other is used to redirect. I just used the "UserFriendlyURL Tool" in the URL Redirect Modules and it comes out with two rules.

Comment: Without the two rules together. clients can visit my sites using both addresses: 

www.example.com/abc.php and www.example.com/abc. And I only want people to see www.example.com/abc even if they have input .php at the end.

Comment: For the second part, I still can't rewrite the URL. I have uploaded an image on my question, what should I put in ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not familiar with this IIS dialogues. With your setup the order of your rules is very important. First of all I suggest disabling your two primary rules and getting the members-rule working. Rewriting `^/member/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$` to `member.php?getuser={R:1}`  can’t be so wrong, even in IIS. As soon as this works correctly, you hopefully can look further.